# Why my android studio telling me to update sdk but i have done it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
on).

I have already Installed latest version of android studio and also updated the sdk
Now whats the problem

Comment: Please share your AndroidManifest.xml and also the version of your AGP.